# Set character limit with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an expression that allows characters only and also rejects any white spaces.

How can I limit the number of characters, lets say 7 characters for example. I'm using this function for a keyup event on an input field, although I can use the maxlength attribute, regex is my preferred method.

```
event.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setting a minimum/maximum character count like: `/[^a-zA-Z]{7,}/g`.

But, I see that you want to accept only letters and a maximum of 7 characters, you can use just  `.substr(0,7)`, You could do it this way:

```js
document.querySelector("input").onkeyup = function(event){
   event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').substr(0,7);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Yes, subsrting makes perfect sense! Sorry, I know I did ask for regex in my question, but this is simple

Answer (score 1):

You can [limit the characters repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) using `{}`.For example if you want to match 7 character which match with `[^a-zA-Z]` using {7} :

```
[^a-zA-Z]{7}
```

> There's an additional quantifier that allows you to specify how many times a token can be repeated. The syntax is {min,max}, where min is zero or a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and max is an integer equal to or greater than min indicating the maximum number of matches.

Comment: I have read this in the documents, however Im struggling to implement this within the code replace()

Comment: @meteorBuzz What you mean by within the code `replace()`? you can just use `[^a-zA-Z]{7}` instead of your regex!